# How to set my website page link in cron job?

Tags: java, php, cron

I am trying to add cron job comment link like [this](http://freejobs.in/styprogram/update_web_minner.php).

This is my page link and I am trying to add this link to the cron job comment section, like `/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/study_program/update_web_minner.php`. But this is wrong.

How to set cron job comment section?

Comment: Grat, you first question seems to have a quite high quality to me. Here is your first upvote. What is important: "But this is wrong." is not enough clear, explain how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just 
edit crontab with `crontab -e`
add your line with the previx `#` like `#my comment`
save the cronjob again.

Thats all.

Comment: I can use # like #home/username/public_html/study_program/update_web_minner.php...but program will not execute..and again path is not currect.